Keycloak behind Traefik returns 502 Bad Gateway
The problem
I am trying to place keycloak behind traefik in order to secure several services and a SPA.
Until then, however, I only want to reach keycloak via my hostname tsl protected with traefik.
what I have tried
In my YML file below, keycloak and traefik are set up.
keycloak is created with a dockerfile as described in the documentation, and a key is also generated.
The created key is not secure, I know that in production I would use a letsencrypt certificate, but I don't want to request new certificates every time I try.
As alias server I have specified my stack host as in the compose file and the IP of my WSL. At the moment I think there might be an error, but I don't know what to change.
In my YML file keycloak is released via traefik with the https port 8443. However, if I only use
https://stack_host..:8443/admin
502 Bad Gateway appears, however everything is looking fine in my Traefik dashboard.

Answer
I have now managed it.
Traefik runs with Keycloak, the TSL encryption is done via traefik and not via keycoak, therefore keycloak must only be accessible via port 8080, it does not require a keypair for keycloak.
I have added another host auth.stack_host in /etc/hosts (under Windows System32/drivers/hosts), which is now reachable under https:auth.stack_host and leads to keycloak.
Here is a boilerplate YML file for keycloak, traefik and a vue SPA. The vue application is listening on https://stack_host:443
Set stack_host to the name of your computer or add another host in the file from above.
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.file.directory=/configuration/
      - --providers.file.watch=true
      - --accesslog
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.gateway.address=:5001
    ports:
      - "172.17.108.255:8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /traefik:/configuration/
    networks:
      - external-network
    mem_limit: 200m
    mem_reservation: 100m

  frontend:
    build: gui
    container_name: ${STACK_NAME}-frontend
    restart: always
    networks:
      - external-network
    command: --brotli --port 8083
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=${STACK_NAME}-external"
      
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`${STACK_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=cors_header"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors_header.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET,OPTIONS,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors_header.headers.accesscontrolallowheaders=*"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors_header.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=https://${STACK_HOST}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors_header.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.cors_header.headers.addvaryheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=8083"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.scheme=http"


  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    build: KeycloakContainer
    restart: always
    command: start
    environment:
      KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.${STACK_HOST}
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_PROXY_HEADERS: xforwarded
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: "true"
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=${STACK_NAME}-external"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`auth.${STACK_HOST}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    networks:
      - external-network
      - internal-network
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080 && echo -e 'GET /health/ready HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: localhost\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\n' >&3 && cat <&3 | grep -q '200 OK'"
        ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20

networks:
  internal-network:
    name: ${STACK_NAME}-internal
    internal: true
  external-network:
    name: ${STACK_NAME}-external
    driver: bridge

Keycloak Dockerfile/ or just use the image if you dont want to import smth.
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.1 as builder
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.1

COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

// load custom theme
COPY ./marvins-theme/ /opt/keycloak/themes/marvins-theme

// import realm
COPY ./realm-config/realm.json /opt/keycloak_import/

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh import --file /opt/keycloak_import/realm.json
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]

